# How can I paginate rows that are returned using with()?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Here is my query:

```
$questions = Questions::with('answers')->where('id', $request->id)->get();
```

It works as well and all fine. It matches a questions plus all its answers. I need to paginate the answers, how can I do that?

As you can see, I don't want to paginate the query directly (in that case we could use `->paginate()` instead of `->get()`). But how can I do that when I'm using `with()` and I want to paginate matched rows in `with()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your own pagination with a [Paginator](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.html).

Or you could just turn the query around:

```
$answers = Answer::whereHas('question', function($q) use ($request) {
    $q->where('id', $request->id);
})->with('question')->paginate();
```

Or

```
$question = Question::find($request->id);
$answers = $question->answers()->paginate();
```

But you can't paginate with `->with()` method.

Comment: Also for my information, what's `question` in `Answer::whereHas('question',` ? The name of the model?

Comment: Name of the relationship in the `Answer` model. You might not have it defined, I just assumed.